Customization Search Criteria for lightning-record-picker
I'm trying to work with the new(ish) lightning-record-picker component. I'm using it to find a record among a table of brand names. Everything is going well until I need to search for GE.
It appears the search doesn't do any sort of "startsWith" preference or anything, so I end up with a list of any records containing g followed by e, or in SOQL syntax LIKE '%GE%', which means my return list has around 50 results, in seemingly no order. And GE isn't even on of the results.
Is there a way to do one of the following:

Adjust the search to prefer "startsWith"
In the filters, reference the currently entered search? I can't see anything about that in any documentation.
Type into the search field in a structured way to do this search properly (like one may do in a Google search)


Dug through the source code on the standard component. They add the search term in with wildcards like so: %${term}%, and they don't seem to store the term anywhere for reference in filtering logic.
So at this time, it appears that this is a limitation to the standard component.
